# Diazo (plone.app.theming) issues with RHEL

Tags: plone, selinux

I recently began working again on trying to get plone.app.theming to work on a RHEL box.  I am building the lxml libraries via buildout as suggested and it still would not work.

The error I was getting is: cannot restore segment prot after reloc: Permission denied on files within the lxml egg directory.  This kept the instances from starting.

After some trial and error and research, I finally found a solution, albeit not a good one, but I did get plone.app.theming working.  The issue seems to be with SELinux enabled.  For testing purposes, I disabled SELinux on this box and wola, after restarting my instances, the whole thing worked.

My questions are this.  What, if anything am I doing wrong to cause this?  Is there a solution that doesn't involve turning SELinux off completely and would there be a buildout based solution to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to [change files' selinux context](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files.html). Though, this isn't linked in any way to Diazo and/or lxml. SELinux is a rude guy.